# Xamarin Native iOS layout

Tags: ios, xamarin, native

I am working with one guy on one mobile App using Xamarin Native. I do the Android part, and the other guy does the iOS part.
I have reviewed his code and noticed that for UI layouts he is using programming code rather than an XML file like in Android, or a XAML file in Xamarin Forms.
As my experience with iOS development is very little I would like to know if it possible to make a UI layout from an XML file in iOS rather than make it programmatically.
My main problem is that when you make layouts programmatically the controller class might get to big as more code is added and is hard for me to review sometimes.
If there is a way you can have a layout file instead in iOS could you please share a very simple example,  lets say a UI with a label and a button (HelloWorld like).

Thank you so much and I hope everyone is doing well.

Comment: Apple has a tool called Interface Builder you can use to design UI layouts.

Comment: Hi Jason, Do you know if it can be used in Xamarin Native?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/designer/?tabs=macos

Comment: You can develop UI by storyboard/xib as listed in the document.

Answer (score 0):

When I used Xamarin native ios there were like two options. First of all you can use the visual designer of xcode. For that there will be some kind of connection of the xcode project in xcode and the xamarin peoject in visual studio for mac That will create some kind of code. It was sometimes buggy and I needed to reload a lot. Another thing some ios developers are doing is not using the visual designer but describing the ui directly from code and build it there.

Apple has a "new" framework called swift ui. That comes closer to the XML approach of android or of an react app. But unfortunately it is not supported in xamarin at all... This was the main reason for me not going with xamarin anymore for new projects.